# ¿Como reutilizar una función de otra page ionic?

Tags: ionic

tengo un proyecto de `ionic` donde cree una función muy compleja en una `page`, y en este momento tengo una segunda `page` donde necesito usar la misma `función` que cree en la primera `page`, la idea no es copiar y pegar tantas lineas de código, ¿Como puedo reutilizar el código de la función que esta en la primera `page`?

**primera-pagina.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-primera-pagina',
  templateUrl: 'primera-pagina.html',
})
export class PrimeraPaginaPage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetallesItemPage');
  }
  MiFuncion(){
     console.log('hola')
  } 
}
```

**segunda-pagina.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PrimeraPaginaPage } from '../primera-pagina/primera-pagina';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-segunda-pagina',
  templateUrl: 'segunda-pagina.html',
})
export class SegundaPaginaPage {

  miPrimeraPagina : any = PrimeraPaginaPage
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      this.miPrimeraPagina.MiFuncion()
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetallesItemPage');
  }
  MiFuncion(){
     console.log('hola')
  } 
}
```

esto me da el siguiente error:

> error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   this.miPrimeraPagina.MiFuncion is not a function TypeError:
>   this.miPrimeraPagina.MiFuncion is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Podrias crear esa funcion en una clase aparte y luego importarla adonde la requieras. Ejemplo:

Yo lo he hecho de esta manera en /misc/utils cree un archivo utils.ts con lo siguiente:

```
 export class StaticMethods {
  static formatSubmitErrors( _errors: any ): any {
    let errors_list =[];
    for ( let key in _errors ) {
      errors_list.push(_errors[key]);
    }
    return errors_list;
  }
}
```

Luego en el page que queria utilizarla:

```
import { StaticMethods } from '../misc/utils';

...
private handleError(error: any): any {
    return {errors: StaticMethods.formatSubmitErrors( error.json() ) };
  }
...
```

Comment: Yo trate de hacer   miPage : any = MiPage, y en el constructor de mi segunda page trato de usar la función asi: this.miPage.MiFuncion(), me sale el siguiente error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.miPage.MiFuncion is not a function
TypeError: this.miPage.MiFuncion is not a function

Comment: Como lo estas declarando, el error te dice que la funcion no esta definida dentro del objeto, estas importando la primera pagina en la segunda??

Comment: Estoy importando el nameSpace asi: import { MiPage } from '../miPage/miPage';

Comment: La verdad es que necesito tanto la función que le comento + todas las variables que ese instancian en la clase de la primera Page

Comment: modifique la pregunta y puse un ejemplo de lo que quiero, pero me sale el error

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas conveniente es usar [Servicios](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/), es la mejor forma de compartir información y funciones entre paginas. Asi:

Servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UtilsService {
    miFuncion(str: any): any {
            return "Funcion ejecutada, parametro: " + str;
    }   
    constructor() {}
}
```

Pagina:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilsService } from '../la-ruta-al-servicio/utils.service';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.utils.miFuncion("Prueba");
    }
    constructor(private utils: UtilsService) { }

}
```

También es necesario declarar el servicio en tu app.module.ts, en el apartado de providers.